# ¿Cómo se hace la Función Logaritmo Natural Que Hay en el Objeto Math?

Tags: vb.net, math

Me gustaría saber cómo se llega al logaritmo natural de un número, contando solo con sumas, restas, multiplicaciones, divisiones, y raíces cuadradas.

El objeto Math.Log Proporciona una Función Que Sería una Solución, Pero ¿Cómo Se Desarrolla esta Función en Concreto?

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede calcular el Log(N) del Objeto Math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoy acabo de solucionar el problema. La cuestión se arregla teniendo las potenciaciones con números reales para hacer una función inversa a base de divisiones del NumLog x NumBase.
La respuesta a esto es larga y hacen falta muchas líneas de código para resolver-lo pero es una regla de proporcionalidades con los números después de haber conseguido la parte entera del logaritmo.